# how can we change unique _id in cloudant DB to custom _id in node red?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

i'm trying to insert an json object in cloudant to create an api, but here the problem is unique _id which is default created by cloudant db. i need to create my own _id, so api will be valuable.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the `_id` attribute on your JSON document before inserting it, Cloudant will use this as the document ID and will not generate one.

Comment: Working, thanks .  One more query can we insert multiple key value pair data under one_id  in cloudant at different timings not at single push

Comment: you have asked this in another question. Better to get the answer over there.

Comment: Mr.Frederic again i'm facing the same problem, sometime custom _is is working but sometime it's not working. whether problem in my side or cloudantbd, can you help me in resolving this?